# If in all subsets of size k there exist at least one pair of elements in a relation...

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, induction, ramsey-theory

I’ve recently got stuck on a theorem that seems to be true, but I am not sure if I am able to prove it:

$\large\forall_{x\in\mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{N})}\exists_{\left\{ y_1,y_2\right\}\subset x \land y_1 \neq y_2}\; \varphi(y_1,y_2) \rightarrow \exists_{x\in \mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{N})}\forall_{\left\{y_1,y_2\right\} \subset x \land y_1 \neq y_2}\;\varphi(y_1,y_2)$

Where $\varphi$ is any symmetric predicate, i.e. $\varphi(y_1,y_2) \iff \varphi(y_2,y_1)$, and $\mathbb{P}_k(\mathbb{X})$ is the set of all subsets of $\mathbb{X}$ of size $k$.

In simple words: for any symmetric relation on $\mathbb{N}$, if every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ of size k contains at least one pair of related elements, then in some subset of size k all pairs of elements are related.

This statement is true for $k = 2$ and for $k = 3$ and while $k = 2$ is easy, $k = 3$ was proved by me using graphs (already a bit harder). I believe the proper method for such a theorem would be a proof by induction, however I can’t make the inductive step.

Any thoughts? I really appreciate any help or hint. I also believe this to be quite an interesting theorem.

#### EDIT:

My proof was like this:

I proved it by deducing without loss of generality how the graph of these relations would behave. I used for this 4 pairs of vertices (each pair having an edge between them, no other edges at the beginning). These edges are given, if by any deductive reasoning we obtain a triangle, then the theorem is proved. Each step of the proof consists of selecting 3 vertices that aren’t connected by any edge and choosing 2 of them and connecting them (in case you can’t do it without the loss of generality, you have to follow all possible routes). At each step you avoid at all cost creating a triangle. I was eventually forced to connect two vertices and by it created a triangle. Should I present the whole proof here? If so do you recommend any tool for drawing graphs and posting it here?

**Proof**:
[Ramsey’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) may be easily used to prove this statement. Solved.

Comment: Givng some details (if not the complete proof) about your proof for the $k=3$ case might give someone an idea.

Comment: I've described the method I used to prove $k = 3$. Should I go more into details? If so, then which tool should I use to create neat graphs?

Comment: I believe it's actually doable to prove $k=3$, by using only 3 pair of pairs.

Comment: For clarity, your "whichever" predicate is meant to model a symmetric relation?  That is, an undirected graph on the nodes $\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Isn't the relation $$\varphi(y_1,y_2)\iff y_1\lt y_2$$ a counterexample for the case $k=2?$ Are you sure you don't want to assume that $\varphi$ is a ***symmetric*** relation? In that case, what you're asking about is just a weak form of Ramsey's theorem.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry I didn't make it clear. It's a symmetric relation. I'll look up to the Ramsey's theorem you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: @bof is the solution you're proposing to just say that $R(k,k)$ is the size of the subgraph that imposes a requirement that there exist a clique, because there can't be any $k$ sized independent sets? Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: @bof:  I encourage you to write up your solution as an Answer, which I would upvote, unless you prefer the OP to try their hand at posting one in more detail than was given by the Comments.  I suspect you would do a better job in this particular instance.

Comment: A curious aspect of the proposed theorem is that with increasing $k$ the premise gets weaker and the conclusion stronger!

Comment: @bof: having read the OP’s comment of Nov 13 at 10:03 I see what I was overlooking, so I have removed my previous comment and am unsure if my answer is worth leaving as it stands.

Answer (score 1):

The premise of your theorem is stronger than you realise, so that your conjecture can be proven as a corollary of a stronger theorem, which I state in graph-theoretical terms:

> Any sufficiently large graph whose every subgraph of some given size is non-empty contains a complete subgraph of any desired size.

It would be helpful to flesh out your statement that it follows from [Ramsey’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) (of which the above is little more than a logical rearrangement) to explain how.

The proof below of the above reformulation is more or less in the spirit of the proof of Ramsey’s theorem (as given in Wikipedia),
but somewhat clumsier, due perhaps to the less symmetrical formulation.

#### A little terminology

Let us write

- $ G $ for the graph,
- $ \overline G $ for its complement,
- $ G.V $ or simply $V$ for the vertices of $G$,
- $ x G $ for the neighbours of a vertex $x$ in $G$,
- an $r$-clique, -subgraph for a clique or subgraph with $r$ vertices, where a [clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Clique_(graph_theory)) is a complete subgraph,
- $ C(G,k,r) $ for the assertion that every $k$-subgraph of $G$ contains an $r$-clique,
- $ C(G,r) $ for $ C(G,|V|,r) $, i.e. the assertion that $G$ contains  an $r$-clique.

#### A stronger theorem

We assert that
$$
\exists f : \mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N : |G.V| > f(k,r) \wedge C(G,k,2) \Rightarrow C(G,r)
$$

#### Proof from first principles

We proceed by induction on $k$ and, within $k$, on $r$.
For $ k = 1 $, the theorem is vacuously true, as $ |V| > 2 \Rightarrow \neg C(G,1,2) $.

Now supposing the theorem proven for $k$ (in combination with all values of $r$), we prove it for $ k+1 $;
we therefore assume $ C(G,k+1,2) $ and that $f(x,y)$ is defined for $ x \leqslant k $.

For $ r=2 $ trivially $ |V| > k \wedge C(G,k,2) \Rightarrow C(G,2) $.

Consider a vertex $x$ and its non-neighbours $ x \overline G $, among which we observe $ C(x \overline G, k, 2) $, whence, by induction:
$$
|x \overline G | > f(k,r) \Rightarrow C(x \overline G ,r)
$$

Hence, in a counterexample to $ C(G,r+1) $, we have:
$$
 \forall x \in V : | x \overline G | < f(k,r+1)
$$

By the induction on $r$ we have an $r$-clique $R$;
if a vertex in $ G-R $ is joined to all of $R$ we have a $(k+1)$-clique.
Otherwise every point in $ G-R $ is not joined to at least one member of $R$,
which limits the size of the complement:
$$
 |G-R| = |G| - r < r f(k,r+1)
$$
i.e.
$$
 |G| < r ( 1 + f(k,r+1) )
$$

Hence in this case we may take $ f(k,r) = r ( 1 + f(k,r+1) ) $ and the theorem holds by induction for all $k$ and $r$.

**Q.E.D**

#### Proof using Ramsey’s theorem

[Ramsey’s Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem) tells us that for $|G| > R(r,k)$, $G$ contains an $r$-clique or independent set of size $k$, or equivalently $ C(G,r) \lor C(\overline G, k) $ but the hypothesis $C(G, k, 2)$ is eqivalent to $ \neg C(\overline G, k) $ so that the theorem I formulated above is a logical rearrangement of Ramsey’s theorem.

Comment: I am wondering whether I ought to remove the proof from first principles, as it does indeed follow trivially from Ramsey’s theorem, which I had managed to overlook.